# In Sencha Touch, how do I do a calculation with inputs received from form fields?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Say I have a form like this:

```
var Sum1 = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    id: 'Sum1',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        title: 'Step 1: Calculating The Sum',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            name: 'num1',
            label: 'First Number'
        },{
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            name: 'num2',
            label: 'Second Number'
        },{
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            name: 'num3',
            label: 'Third Number'
        },{
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            name: 'num4',
            label: 'Fourth Number'
            },{
            xtype: 'button',
            name: 'CalcSum',
            ui: 'Confirm',
            text: 'Calculate Sum',
            handler: function() {
                Ext.getCmp('Total').setValue('1');
            }
        }]
    },{
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    title: 'Calculated Total',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Total',
        id: 'Total',
        placeHolder: 'Your Calculated Total'
    }]
});
```

What I want to do is to use the values `num1-4` in some method that sums them and returns a value - which is then set in my textfield `Total`.

I am very new to Sencha Touch, and am using Sencha Touch 2.0, so would love any assistance.

Thanks.

Comment: you can provide unique Id for every numberfield, and u can track that number field by using that respective Id

Comment: @Nag Isn't that what the `name` attribute does? But I meant...what would the code look like? Where would I declare the method definition and how would I call it? The docs for Sencha Touch go through dealing with classes and stuff...not so much regular methods.

Comment: Actually if you provide an id for that you can get that value in fieldset by using getItemId( ) method.Please refer the following link for better understanding. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Number

Comment: @Nag what I am asking is, what would the syntax look like if I were to write a method called `CalculateTotal` that took those variables `num1-4` and returned the sum/calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I would listen to the `blur` method. This method will be called after your textfield loose focus. Then you can do your thing and spit it out in the `total` field?

See API: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Text

Perhaps:

```
blur: function() {
  // code here
}
```

or (I think better)

```
blur: yourFunctionHere()
```

**UPDATE 2012-01-30:**
You can define this in the same file, or even per field:

```
items: [{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        name : 'num1',
        label: 'First Number',
        blur : function() {
             console.log('You blurred me!');
             // get current value of total field and sum it with me (if I am not null!)
        }
    },{
```

Better way is to defin one function, you can do it in the same file;

```
items: [{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        name : 'num1',
        label: 'First Number',
        blur : doCalculateTotals()
    },{
```

Comment: But where do I define this function? In the same file as everything else above?

Comment: Yes, I you do not use the MVC approach you can define it in the same file. In MVC approach you should define it in the controller. But for this case, your fine in the same file.